# How to add a shadow to an UIImageView which fits the shape of the image content but with some rotation and shift effect

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics

I have been looking for the solution on the web for a long time. Most tutorials are fairly simple about adding shadow to a UIView. I also noticed that if we add a shadow to an UIImageView. The shadow shape could perfectly fit the shape of the content image if the image itself has alpha channel in it. Say for example, if the image is an animal with transparent background, the shadow shape is also the same as that animal (not a rectangle shadow as same as UIImageView frame).

But these are not enough. What I need to do is to add some changes to the shadow so it may have some rotation angle and compressed (squeezed or shift) effect so that looks like the sunlight comes from a certain spot.

To demonstrate what I need, I upload 2 images below, which I captured from the Google Map App created by Apple. You can imagine the Annotation Pin is an image which has the Pin shape, so the shadow is also "pin shaped", but it is not simply "offset" with a CGSize, you can see the top of the shadow is shifted right about 35 degrees and slightly squeezed the height.

When we tap and hold and pin, the shadow is also animated away from the pin, so I believe that such shadow can be made programmably.

The best shadow tutorial I can found so far is http://nachbaur.com/blog/fun-shadow-effects-using-custom-calayer-shadowpaths But unfortunately, that cannot make this effect.

If anyone know the answer or know any better words to search for, please let me know. Thank you.

(Please note that the shape of the image is dynamic in the App, so using any tool like Photoshop to pre-render the shadow is not an option.)

[image: the annotation pin shadow]

[image: the annotation pin shadow when tap and drop]

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this would be to implement or include a 3d engine into your project that includes options for dynamic lighting.  Even if your application is fully 2D the concept you're implying is a 3D problem based on the position of the light, the object causing the shadow, and the surface the shadow is reflected on.

Comment: I assume you have tried working with the `.shadowPath` property?

Comment: Yes, I tried the shadowPath, but I am not quite familiar with getting the shadowPath based on the original shape of the UIImageView content (which is an UIImage with transparent background) --- Maybe this is the key point of this question. The tutorial in nachbaur.com does mention creating shadowPath. But it is creating an oval shadow path or a shape based on the UIImageView (which is a rectangle).

Answer (score 2):

In order to create dynamic effects like this, you have to use Core Graphics. It's incredibly powerful once you know how to use it. Basically you need to set a skew transform on the context, set up a shadow and draw the image. You will probably have to use transparency layers as well.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you can use CALayer shadows, since that is meant to solve a specific use-case.  The approach Apple takes with the pin marks on the map is to have two separate images that are created ahead of time (e.g. in Photoshop) and they position them within the map relative to a reference point.

If you really do need to do this at run-time, it should still be possible by using either Core Graphics or ImageKit.  To get a blurred shadow appearance, you can use the kCICategoryBlur CIFilter.  You can then convert the image to grayscale.  And to get that compressed look you just need to resize and skew the image.

Once you have two separate images, you can either take the CGImageRef for the shadow image and can set that as the content of another sublayer, or you can add it as a separate view.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what all the shapes are, you could just render a shadow image in Photoshop or something.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I know we can use Photoshop. But my shape is dynamic and could be any shape in the App, so the shadow cannot be pre-rendered.